# How to get difference based on date in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have like below mentioned two table:

Table1

```
ID      Unique_Value
T-1     OI-45
T-4     OI-45
T-8     OI-45
T-7     OI-46
T-6     OI-49
```

Table2

```
ID        Date                    Value
T-1       2018-01-01 15:13:22     10
T-4       2018-03-15 18:10:45     15
T-8       2018-05-12 05:17:43     25
T-7       2018-04-01 15:13:22     12
T-6       2018-06-01 15:13:22     18
```

I have joined the Table2 `ID` with Table1 `ID` and get the `Unique_Value`, based on the unique value and order by `Date` in Descending order and group by `Unique_Value`, I want to get the difference value of a particular `ID` from the previous Value.

Required Output would be:

```
ID        Date                    Value     Unique_Value     Difference
T-1       2018-01-01 15:13:22     10        OI-45            [Null]
T-4       2018-03-15 18:10:45     15        OI-45            5
T-8       2018-05-12 05:17:43     25        OI-45            10
T-7       2018-04-01 15:13:22     12        OI-46            [Null]
T-6       2018-06-01 15:13:22     18        OI-49            [Null]
```

I have tried using Lead Log but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `lag()` function - it will work for mysql version 8.0+

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea2e283f716043f33dea3f7644280adb)**

```
select id,Date,value,Unique_Value,case when prevval is null then null else value-prevval end as Difference
from
(
select t1.Id,t1.Unique_Value,t2.Date,t2.value,lag(t2.value,1) over(partition by t1.Unique_Value order by t2.Date) as prevval
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
)A
```

For Mysql Version 5.7 you can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddf5f77a8654ca8ed6a069a364e36560)**

```
    SET @quot=0, @latest=0, @comp=''

    select id, Unique_Value,d,value,case when latest=1 then c=null else c end as difference
    from
    (
    select id,Unique_Value,d,value,c,IF(@comp<>Unique_Value,1,0) as LATEST,@comp:=Unique_Value as company from
    (
    select t1.Id,t1.Unique_Value,value,t2.d,value-@quot as c,@quot:=value
    from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
    order by t1.Unique_Value,t2.d
    )A order by Unique_Value,d
    )B
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  d          value    Unique_Value    Difference
T-1 2018-01-01  10      OI-45   
T-4 2018-03-15  15      OI-45            5
T-8 2018-05-12  25      OI-45            10
T-7 2018-04-01  12      OI-46   
T-6 2018-06-01  18      OI-49
```

Comment: Getting syntax error at `over(partition by t1.Unique_Value order by t2.Date) as prevval` this line.

Comment: @VectorJX, have you checked the demo

Comment: Yes, In demo its working fine but not in my actual DB :(

Comment: @VectorJX, what is the error you got - please share that

Comment: Someting like server version for the right syntax to use near `(partition by t1.Unique_Value order by t2.Date) as prevval`

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: The version of my MySql is 5.7.16-log

Comment: didn;t find any alternative for this for MySql 5.7.16

Comment: @VectorJX, I've updated my answer for mysql version 5.7 - you can check now

Comment: @VectorJX, in demo it perfectly matches with your expected output, isn't it?

Comment: fa06: Yes, but Don;t know why there is difference in database. is it because the value stored in db like 100,000.0000??